# How do I add a parameter for an anchor/hash to a RedirectToRouteResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to use a RedirectToRouteResult to redirect to a url like /users/4#Summary.  Using ASP.NET MVC 1.0, I haven't been able to find a way to do that - have I missed it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should properly build your routes in route table. Eg.:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute" ,"{controler}/{id}#{detail}" ,new { controller = "users", action = "index", id = (string)null, detail = "Summary" });
```

Answer (score 6):

UrlHelper.GenerateUrl includes a fragment parameter.  I created an extension method

```
        public static string Action(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, string fragment, object routeValues)
        {
            return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
                routeName: null,
                actionName: actionName,
                controllerName: controllerName,
                routeValues: new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(routeValues),
                fragment: fragment,
                protocol: null,
                hostName: null,
                routeCollection: url.RouteCollection,
                requestContext: url.RequestContext,
                includeImplicitMvcValues: true /*helps fill in the nulls above*/
            );
        }
```

Then I created a RedirectToFragmentResult class

```
public class RedirectToFragmentResult: RedirectResult
{
    public UrlHelper Url {get;set;}
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Fragment { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }
    public RedirectToFragmentResult(UrlHelper url, string action, string controller, string fragment, object routeValues)
        :base(url.Action(action, controller, fragment, routeValues))
    {
        Url = url;
        Action = action;
        Controller = controller;
        Fragment = fragment;
        RouteValues = routeValues;
    }
}
```

Then you can just create a new RouteValueDictionary(result.RouteValues) in your unit test to check it the way you would with a RedirectToRouteResult.

Comment: Thanks @Joel This appears to work very well. There's no need for the local URL property though (which throws up a 'hides' warning). I've tested with lines removed: `public UrlHelper Url {get; set;}` and `Url = url;` - any reason why this is there?

Comment: I used that for debugging convenience, so I can have access to the urlhelper from the watch window, but you're correct that base(url.Action is that last real time that it's used and it's unnecessary for testing)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, take a look here:

[Linking to location on page (#id) through ASP.NET MVC mechanisms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071414/linking-to-location-on-page-id-through-asp-net-mvc-mechanisms)

I ended up creating a route using #.

Answer (score 0):

I do a something like that on my site [here](http://ksischool.com/Activities/11#page2). But it's not with `RedirectToRouteResult`. `RedirectToRouteResult` does not support including an anchor part to the url.

You need to build the link yourself and perhaps even the logic to handle the processing of the anchor part - as i did. My application tries to replicate functionality similar to that of the Facebook photo gallery views. Each link to a different page must have a unique url, so for this i use the anchor part. But coz it does not translate direct to a route i have to parse the anchor part of the url manually on the page and use ajax to load in the appropriate content. This is what i wanted so it works for me.

Comment: That's just it; I know I can build a URL myself, but I want to benefit from strongly-typed checks in my unit-tests when asserting, for example.

Comment: i see. well i think you're out of luck then

Answer (score 0):

Download the [source code of MVC](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet) and check out how RedirectToRouteResult works

There may be better ways but a simple inheritance of RedirectToRouteResult and an override of
ExecuteResult to allow an optional anchor part should fix the problem