# Linking to location on page (#id) through ASP.NET MVC mechanisms?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, routes, hyperlink

My example:

I have a `View` that presents a set of div tags that has content populated from the datamodel.

[Multiple of these, with different location_id, naturally]

```
<div>
    <a name="location_id"></a>
    Content
</div>
```

Now, I have a form [in its own view] that submits content that adds another record to the datamodel. Once the record is create and submitted, I redirect back to the `Action` that returns the `View` with the `<div>` listing.

My challenge:

I'd like the page to focus the `<div>` block that was just created. Ideally I'd like to do this without the use of javascript, - I'd like to use an #location_id ending to the URL. 
Like so: `http://site/Controller/Action/Id#12` (or something along those lines).

Anyone got any tips on how to go about doing this?

**Edit:** I cannot use the controller's `Redirect` method (or anything involving a raw url. It needs to be routed either through `Controller/Action` or `Route` mechanisms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time...

I just remembered that you can separate route segments with other character literals than '/',

so naturally I can build a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"MyRoute",
"{controller}/{action}/{id}#{locid}",
 new { ... });
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When returning from an action you probably use RedirectToAction() you can pass in the route values.

You can have route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
"DisplayDivsRoute",
"{controller}/{action}/{focusedDivId}", // URL with parameters
new {controller = "Content", action = "Display", focusedDivId = "1"}, null );
```

When in your Post action (when you are saving the new content object) you can then

```
return RedirectToAction()
```

HTH

Comment: If however you would like to base it on Routes then you can use RedirectToRoute() and construct the params for it by hardcoding it or by looking at your RouteTable.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 3, you can use the fragment argument in this Html.ActionLink overload function:

public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    string protocol,
    string hostName,
    **string fragment**,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own question. Redirect to a URL similar to the one you have given (http://site/Controller/Action/Id#12), and generate an anchor tag in your view with a name attribute just before the record you want to jump to.

Comment: :-) Well, the "Redirect to a URL" part is obvious of course, I am looking for the way to do it from the controller. I should have mentioned that I cannot redirect to a "raw url", I need to base my routing on either Actions or Routes.